# How to identify the essential elements of this paragraph?

Tags: sentence-construction

The wind -driven rain came sheeting across the windows of the lighthouse. The seas roared their waves and thundered agaisnt the rock on which it was stood. The man-made construction  vibrated with the assault of Nature. Inside the Lighthouse Keeper read his newspaper, seemingly indifferent to the tempest around him.

What I have identified are:
1. Lighthouse and its keeper.
2. Tempest.
3. Newspaper.
4. Man-made.

Should I identify more? Thank you :)

Comment: *Essential element of a paragraph* is not a linguistic category, so I'm afraid this question is Off Topic here. It might be On Topic at [writers.se], but I doubt it: *essential element* is not an established literary or critical category either. The question appears to me to rest on the approach of a particular teacher or textbook to teaching literary reading or writing, and is consequently meaningless outside that idiosyncratic context.

Answer (score 3):

The most important elements of this paragraph are verbosity and [the color purple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) . It can be boiled down to *A violent rainstorm shook the lighthouse. Inside, the keeper languidly read his newspaper*. "Man-made" is irrelevant, as is "newspaper".